# Zabbix - Web Service timeout

Tags: docker, zabbix

I am trying to create scheduled reports but my zabbix web service is not working. I always get this message:

```
Cannot connect to web service: timeout was reached
```

I am using Zabbix Composed installation on Ubuntu server with the docker. Here are images which I am using right now:

```
zabbix\zabbix-web-service:ubuntu-latest
zabbix\zabbix-web-nginx-mysql:ubuntu-latest
zabbix\zabbix-server-mysql:ubuntu-latest
zabbix\zabbix-agent:ubuntu-latest
mysql:8.0
busybox:latest
```

I were so desperate that I upgraded my whole solution to the :latest images from the version 5.4 and hoped it will solve my problem - not helped.

I used the wireshark to check TCP traffic and not helped - my zabbix web service will not respond to my zabbix server (1 minute timeout).

I tried to generate a report from an empty dashboard because of data size - not helped.

I tried to set debug logs to level 5 and read logs through the docker - not helped.

I found out that scheduled reports will be generated only when I restart my zabbix web service docker container and immediately after the container startup, I will generate a report. This is the only way when I was able to generate a report. Little bit after the container will be started, I will receive the error again

Answer (score 1):

I am also deploying zabbix in docker, and I can use scheduled reports normally.

I deployed the following container in docker:

- mysql:5.7
- zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql:alpine-latest
- zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-mysql:alpine-latest
- zabbix/zabbix-web-service:alpine-latest

#### zabbix-server-mysql

```sh
docker run --name zabbix-server -d --restart always \
    --link mysql:zabbix-mysql \
// ...
    -e ZBX_STARTREPORTWRITERS="2" \
    -e ZBX_WEBSERVICEURL="http://docker:10053/report" \
    -p 10051:10051 \
    -d zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql:alpine-latest
```

#### zabbix-web

```sh
docker run --name zabbix-web -d --restart always \
  --link mysql:zabbix-mysql \
  --link zabbix-server:zabbix-server \
// ...
  -p 80:8080 \
  zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-mysql:alpine-latest
```

#### zabbix-web-service

```sh
docker run --name zabbix-web-service -d --restart always \
    -e ZBX_ALLOWEDIP="127.0.0.1,192.168.1.0/24,172.17.0.0/16" \
    -e ZBX_TLSACCEPT=unencrypted \
    -e ZBX_DEBUGLEVEL=5 \
    -v zabbix_agent2_enc:/var/lib/zabbix/enc \
    --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN \
    -p 10053:10053 \
    zabbix/zabbix-web-service:alpine-latest
```

Here you need to pay attention to setting **ZBX_ALLOWEDIP**:

- The ip address pool of the container is `172.17.0.4/16`
- The ip address of the docker host is `192.168.1.2/24`

#### Configure Zabbix frontend

> - Proceed to the Administration → General → Other parameters frontend menu section
> - Specify the full URL of the Zabbix web interface in the Frontend URL parameter.
>   https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/appendix/install/web_service#zabbix_frontend

My zabbix web interface url is `http://docker/zabbix.php`, I set **Frontend URL** to `http://docker`.
Don't follow the picture in the document, set **Frontend URL** to `http://docker/zabbix`.

You can try to access `http://docker/zabbix.php?action=dashboard.print&dashboardid=1`, it should display the dashboard correctly.

If you set **Frontend URL** to `http://docker/zabbix` according to the document, you will access `http://docker/zabbix/zabbix.php?action=dashboard.print&dashboardid=1` and get `File not found.`

Comment: I tried to set-up my web service and my zabbix server as you wrote. Definitely it helped somehow because next day I received reports. Anyway when I click on the test button in my scheduled report it again failed.
Today I received alerts about a High CPU and a High disk IO usage on my Zabbix server. I found out that this problem was my web service which exhausted resources on my server. When I stopped web-service container everything goes back to normal.
I think there are some real issues with this service at least in the docker solution.